# figuring out what eax is pointing to using gdb

Tags: assembly, gdb

I have the following assembly language

```
cmp    %ebx,(%eax)
```

and I want to know what I can do to figure out what eax is pointing to?

I used the i r command in gdb to show the stack content, and learned that ebx is my input value, and eax is 134522400.

What do the numbers represent? I tried calling x 134522400 and x/s 134522400, but both just returned to me "\372\001". I am fairly new to assembly and gdb, so I am not sure what other tools I can use to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a pointer notation, to the tune:

```
print *$eax
```

or even

```
print *(char *)$eax
```

(casting to arbitrary types actually works).